# Will email bounce back if send through Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have one Google Script, through which I am sending out 1 email after every 10-15 minutes between day hours 11 am to 2 pm on Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday only. So, I am sending 18 emails in 3 hours, and which means 54 emails in 3 days of a every week.

*The email is sent to only one recipient at a time having my own email address as BCC, and there are no further CC or BCC.*

I have list of email ids in Google Excel sheet, so after every 10 minutes one email id form the list is selected and an email with attachment is sent to that email address. Once this is done the email address is moved to "Email Sent Done" sheet indicating that we don't need to send mail again to this email address.

Few things I am worried about are:

1) Will I get bounce back email if the email address is not existent when I am sending emails using Google Script?

2) How will I know if the email which I am sending using Google Script is Bounced Back?

3) Will my account will get disabled for sending out scheduled emails using Google Script?

Please help to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send an email with MailApp in Apps Script it sends from the account under which the script is executing.  (eg youraccount@gmail.com).  You will receive any bouncebacks in the inbox of that account. Likewise, you will see the sent emails under the Sent label of that account.

There are quotas for mail, as long as you stay within those limits and are following Google's terms and conditions you should not have any issues with your account.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas